# Export To Disk throws error 'The System cannot find the specified path'

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I am using the following code to export a crystal report in pdf format.

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" | textBox2.Text == "")
{
}
else
{
    string filename = "\\" + textBox1.Text + ".pdf";

    CreateEmptyFile(filename);
    string file = textBox2.Text + "\\" + textBox1.Text + ".pdf";
    labelget();
    try
    {
         int idx = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
         string parv = dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
         ReportDocument wordreport = new ReportDocument();
         wordreport.Load(@"C:\\FOLDER\\TESTREPORT.rpt");
         wordreport.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "xxxxxxx", localhost, database);
         wordreport.Refresh();
         wordreport.SetParameterValue("bill_no", parv);
         wordreport.SetParameterValue("fromterminal", this.terminal);
         wordreport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, file);
    }
    catch (Exception em)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error is: " + em);
    }
}
```

Error Occurs in line `wordreport.ExportToDisk`  saying the system could not find the specified path. I checked the permissions for the path where I created the PDF file, It all looks good. 
How do i rectify this error?

Comment: What is you input in `textBox2.Text` and `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: @"C:\\ __either__ double back-slashes or `@` !!

Comment: Hi,
textBox2.Text = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"
textBox1.Text = "PDFfile"

Comment: @TaW, Can you brief your comment! I am unable to get it.

Comment: You need to pass `file` into `CreateEmptyFile(file);` before calling `wordreport.ExportToDisk`

Comment: And also check `file` is exist before calling `wordreport.ExportToDisk`

Comment: @X-TECH, i passed the same in createemptyfile method..
public void CreateEmptyFile(string filename)
        {
            filename = textBox2.Text + filename;
            File.Create(filename).Dispose();
        }

Comment: and i check if the file is created before the it executes the line wordreport.ExportToDisk

Comment: What returns `File.Exist(file)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate Crystal Report in PDF format while passing Multiple Parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104381/how-to-generate-crystal-report-in-pdf-format-while-passing-multiple-parameters)

Comment: I need to login to sharepath with user id and password. Tried the above and didn't work for me. So any new idea?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Reason and answer for my question. I missed to add DSN details in admin tools.